# Set and update validation on form array in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In angular 4 i am creating a form that has a form array like so

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  required:false,
  selectType: ['', [Validators.required]],
  items: this.formBuilder.array([this.buildItems()])
})

...
buildItems() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({ 
     name: ['', [Validators.required]] 
});
```

This builds the form and i can i add remove etc from this form and items in the form. 
What i am now trying to achieve is that when the `selectType` is equal to `custom` ( which is set as a radio button value on the form ) then i need to change the validation of the items `name` and clear its validation requirement.

I have done an set and update on a another form like so

```
  changeValidation() {
      if(condition){
          this.form.get('name').setValidators(Validators.required);
          this.form.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
      }
  }
```

Which works fine, however i am not sure how to update the validations on the form array. I have tried

```
this.items.clearValidators();
this.items.updateValueAndValidity();
```

I dont get any errors but it also doesn't work. Which kind of makes sense because i am not targeting a specific `FormControl` however how do i specify a specific `FormControl` when the `FormControls` are an array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how do i specify a specific FormControl when the FormControls are an
>   array?

You have to use `at` method described [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at) to get a single control:

```
this.items.at(0).clearValidators();
```

If you want to clear validators for the `name` control, do like that:

```
 this.items.at(0).controls.name.clearValidators();
```

If you want to remove validators for every control, it seems that form array doesn't provide such API. You have to iterate over the form array controls and remove validators for each control:

```
this.items.controls.forEach(c => c.clearValidators());
```

Comment: Will that not update for the `formControl` at index 0. I want to update the whole form array

Comment: I want to clear the validators for `name: ['', [Validators.required]]` in `this.items`

Comment: then do like that `this.items.at(0).controls.name.clearValidators();`, I've updated the ansewr

Comment: This did not work for me.. I had to run .controls[0].updateValueAndValidity(); for each change made otherwise the validations did not always get updated

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? maybe create some stackblitz demo?

Comment: The thing is, should the control be revalidated because an external condition changed, you'll need to call yourself updateValueAndValidity(). https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6824. Old post but its the same in angular 4. I hade to call this method if any validators changed dynamically..

Comment: @NetProvoke, what you're saying is that after removing a validator we need to trigger validation manually?

Comment: "If we did not apply updateValueAndValidity, the form status will remain as VALID because we only updated the validation rules of each field. We did not trigger any updates." see https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-conditional-validation-in-angular-2-model-driven-forms

Comment: how to clear validation from formarray in runtime

Comment: there is no need for looping one can simply do this `this.items.at(i).get('control_name').clearValidators();`

Answer (score 0):

You can update all your FormArray validators with casting:

```
$ (this.form.get('name') as FormArray).setValidators([Validators.required]);

$ (this.form.get('name') as FormArray).updateValueAndValidity();
```

In the same way, you can get FormArray and clear values...